# The limit of a sequence with two-dimensional indexes?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence $x_{m,n}$ with two dimensional indexes $(m,n)∈\Bbb{N}×\Bbb{N}$, what is definition of the limit $\lim_{m,n→∞}x_{m,n}$?

The following is my guess, is it right? Thank you!

> $\lim_{m,n→∞}x_{m,n} = x$ if $∀ϵ>0∃M,N∈\Bbb{N}$ st. $m>M,n>N$ implies $|x_{m,n}-x|<ϵ$

Comment: Yes: your guess is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out, your answer is correct. However, you can simplify the definition slightly by only requiring one lower bound on $m$ and $n$. That is, you say the sequence converges if there is $N^\prime \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n > N^\prime$ implies $\vert x_{m,n}-x \vert < \epsilon.$ This definition implies yours because if it holds, you can take $M=N = N^\prime.$ And if you assume your definition, then you can take $N^\prime = \max\{M,N\}$. So they are equivalent.